# Exclude executable files from selecting when using UIDocumentPickerViewController

Tags: ios, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

I've a requirement where our app should not select any executable file from iCloud Drive as an attachment. But since I'm using UIDocumentPickerViewController to initialize it, I'm not sure how to exclude kUTTypeExecutable UTI. Please let me know.

```
NSArray *options = @[(__bridge NSString *)kUTTypeItem, (__bridge NSString *) kUTTypeContent, (__bridge NSString *) kUTTypeData, (__bridge NSString *) kUTTypePackage, (__bridge NSString *) kUTTypeDiskImage, @"com.apple.iwork.pages.pages", @"com.apple.iwork.numbers.numbers", @"com.apple.iwork.keynote.key", (__bridge NSString *)kUTTypeFileURL];
UIDocumentPickerViewController *import =
[[UIDocumentPickerViewController alloc] initWithDocumentTypes:options
                                                     inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeImport];
```